# set a parameter in the url via post

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

I would like to set a parameter in the url via post but this page only perform a method and update the page with h: commandButton.

```
<h:commandButton value="Simular" 
                action="#{simulador.simular()}" 
                style="margin:0 4px 0 0;"   
                immediate="true">
       <f:ajax render="@form" immediate="true"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In order to inject a parameter in the url you should perform a complete postback instead of ajax. There's also a way to do that using javascript to get bookmarkable urls. What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: @Xtreme: your first statement is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs are only changed on synchronous requests. Adding a query string to URL is only possible on GET requests. Sending a redirect after POST is one way to create a synchronous GET request.

```
public String simular() {
    // ...

    return "page.xhtml?foo=42&faces-redirect=true";
}
```

This will redirect to `/context/page.xhtml?foo=42`.

If you actually don't need to perform any business logic in the action method based on the postback, then you can also just use a normal button instead of a command button.

```html
<h:button value="Simular" outcome="page.xhtml">
    <f:param name="foo" value="42" />
</h:button>
```